# Join over three tables

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I have the following tables:

```
items id, principaluri, title
principals id, uri, name
members principal_id, member_id
```

The items principaluri is a reference to the principals uri field. The members table defines relationships between principals, means a member of a principal has access to the items of the principal in principal_id. How does the select look like to get all items of a principal?

To get the principals for a membership I do

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM principals p
LEFT JOIN members m ON m.principal_id = p.id
WHERE p.id = m.principal_id and p.uri = 'myuri'
```

But now I need to get all items from the list.

--- UPDATE ---

In the principals table I have also records like

```
20, 'principals/admin', 'main account'
21, 'principals/admin/read', 'read access'
22, 'principals/admin/write', 'write access'
30, 'principals/test', 'main account'
31, 'principals/test/read', 'read access'
32, 'principals/test/write', 'write access'
```

The member table looks like:

```
21,30
22,30
```

which means the user test has read and write access to the items of the admin user.

But in the items table I have entries like:

```
100, 'principals/admin', 'Foo'
101, 'principals/admin', 'Bar'
```

Comment: What do you mean with formatted?

Comment: So the items table has direct references to principals via `principaluri` and indirect relationships to principals via the `members` table?  Is that right? What's the story there?

Comment: The reference is to 'principals/admin/read' but the items are associated to 'principals/admin'. That's the point. Check out the fiddle from @Mahmoud http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48509/5

Comment: Ok, so supposing you searched for the principal "principals/admin", what are you expecting to get as results from the query, given the above sample data? What is the expected result if you searched for "principals/test"?

Comment: In both cases?  And is this relationship recursive?  If there were a 'principals/user' associated with 'principals/test/read' would they have access to the admin items too?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22767/discussion-between-laoneo-and-jlrishe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a nested query, but it seems to do the job:

```
SELECT i.*, mainp.uri mainuri, mp.memberuri, mp.linkuri access
FROM items i
LEFT OUTER JOIN principals mainp
   ON mainp.uri = i.principaluri
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT memberp.uri memberuri, linkp.uri linkuri
     FROM principals memberp
      INNER JOIN members m on memberp.id = m.member_id
      INNER JOIN principals linkp on m.principal_id = linkp.id) as mp
  ON mp.linkuri LIKE CONCAT(i.principaluri, '%')
WHERE mainp.uri = 'principals/test' OR mp.memberuri = 'principals/test'
```

Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7acc8/4

Comment: The only drawback on this solution is that there is no way to determine on the outer select which is the original principal. This is desirable because I need to know if it is a read or write relationship. Any clue how to solve this?

Comment: There may be a way to do it using outer joins instead.  I can take a look tomorrow.  But how do you want it handled if the member principal belongs to both the /read and /write principal, as is the case in your sample data?  Should that produce two rows in the output?

Comment: I've modified the fiddle when there is a third user added with no membership to other principals it returns this item too which is wrong.

Comment: @Laoneo Ok, I think I've got it now, and this time the results include the intermediate principal uri when it's an indirect link from the member to the principal.  Please have a look.

Comment: The problem is that the values of the linked account appear two times.

Comment: Yes, I already asked you how you want to address that: _But how do you want it handled if the member principal belongs to both the /read and /write principal, as is the case in your sample data? Should that produce two rows in the output?_ The linked account has both read and write access, so there is one row for the read association and one row for the write association.